# cassandra table modeling for EDI data

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to create tables to insert EDI data into Cassandra database. As all of you know there are more than 300+ fields in EDI table, What is the best way to create tables. Now I know we will not need all the 300+ fields , but definitely we will be using about 100-120 fields and the rest of the fields must be saved incase we need them in future.  Now out of these 120 + fields we might use 12-15 for search purpose. Let us assume these are some of the fields and we have more of them say close to 300+

**Shipment  ID Number   Date    Reference Number    Equipment Number

Shipper Name    Shipper ID  Shipper Addr1   Shipper Addr2   Shipper City    Shipper State   Shipper Zip
Consignee Name  Consignee ID    Consignee Addr  Consignee Addr2 Consignee City  Consignee State     Consignee Zip   Contact Name    Phone
Item No.    Authorization No.   Lading Desc.    Lading Qty  Packaging Code  Weight (Pounds) Commodity Code

SSCC Application ID
Purchase Order  Reference ID    Unit    Quantity,
A   B   C   D   ….. AA  AB  AC  …..     ZZ**

Now out of these  say we need
**ID Number,    Reference Number,  Equipment Number, A, AD, GG, ….upto 15 as search fields**,

Now what is the best way to model tables in this scenario.

Case 1) Keep all the fields in one table. 
    Well this sounds good but the Table is going to be huge. Search needs too many secondary indexes. Please let me know if this is a good approach or If my thinking is wrong.

Case 2) Split the table into 6 or 7 tables with necessary fields and just for information sake fields. 
    Say Table one: **Shipment   ID Number   Date    Reference Number    Equipment Number  Consignee Name    Consignee ID    Consignee Addr  Consignee Addr2 Consignee City  Consignee State     Consignee Zip   Contact Name    Phone   A   D   FA  … etc say upto 40 fields**

Assuming Table one has mostly used fields.
    Say Table two:
**Item No.  Authorization No.   Lading Desc.    Lading Qty  Packaging Code  Weight (Pounds) Commodity Code … and say upto 200 fields or so …**

Assume there are unto six or seven tables as well

Questions regarding to Case2) 
    1) How do I achieve joins in case I need so.
    2) Most of the time I read suggestions as de-normalize the data and repeat the fields in both the tables. 
        2a) if so how do I insert the data into both the fields do I right my code in such a way or Do I use some other tools like Spark etc..
        2b)  What is the best way to achieve Joins in these scenarios.
        2c) Also what is the best way to still achieve search scenarios with minimal Secondary indexes.

I know the question is vague and needs lot of assumptions but still I would appreciate if you can answer this. I am looking more towards the way my thinking should go . I have gone though many notes but did not find any solutions. I am only reading suggestions , mostly telling me to use de-normalized data . But how do we achieve it.

Please make as many assumptions as possible , I will try to understand, and keep open in using Spark and Cassandra where ever required. Please try to explain it as clearly as possible with example if possible so that it will be clear.

I appreciate the effort you will be taking in answering these questions.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: If you want to be able to query on anything at anytime you will need to use spark, it can do the joins etc. I recommend not using any secondary indexes on this, asking for a world of hurt. Plan out your queries and build a table for each them, with all the data that query needs. If you expect to have to read the entire data set to handle queries, setup spark or use a relational db. There are no joins in cassandra and secondary indexes are for very specific use cases (not this).

Comment: Thanks Chris. When you say create tables based on query . Do you mean I have to create multiple tables for same set of Data. Say I have Table one ( (1,2 p.k),3,4,5,6,7) as fields. and I need to query based in 1,2 and also 5,6 . In that case do you want me to create one more table Two ((5,6, p.k)1,2,3,4).  If not, what is the right way?